# Using Jackson in Jersey with multiple configured ObjectMappers

Tags: jersey, jackson, jax-rs, jackson-modules

Is it possible to setup Jersey using Jackson for serialization/deserialization using multiple configured `ObjectMappers`?

What I would like to be able to do is register a "default" Jackson `ObjectMapper` and then have the ability to register another feature which provides an `ObjectMapper` with some specialized configuration which under certain circumstance will "override" the "default" `ObjectMapper`.

For example, this `ContextResolver` would be for the "default" mapper:

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper mObjectMapper;

    public JacksonMapperProvider() {
        mObjectMapper = createMapper();
    }

    protected abstract ObjectMapper createMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = createMapper();

        return mapper
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mObjectMapper;
    }
}
```

And this `ContextResolver` would be to override the "default" mapper:

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SpecializedMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper mObjectMapper;

    public SpecializedMapperProvider() {
        mObjectMapper = createMapper();
    }

    protected abstract ObjectMapper createMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = createMapper();

        return mapper
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
            .registerModule(new SpecializedModule1())
            .registerModule(new SpecializedModule2());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        if(SomeType.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return mObjectMapper;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I see in the `JacksonJsonProvider` code that Jackson supports `ObjectMapper` provider injection/resolution.  However, in practice, what I am seeing is that the "order" of the providers seems random (I'm guessing it's not, but I can't sort out how to control the order).  Sometimes the "override" comes before the "default" and everything works, but on the next server startup the order changes.

I have attempted to get this to work in a number of ways including:

- Registering the `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>` implementations manually (in differing orders)
- Registering the `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>` implementations via `@Provider` annotations
- Specifying a priority when registering

I am using the following:

- Jersey 2.8
- Jackson 2.3.3

Perhaps I am taking a completely incorrect approach?
Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? 
Maybe I should just define two separate JAX-RS applications and have a single ObjectMapper configuration for each?

Comment: What I found is once you have `ObjectMapper defaultMapper = return new ObjectMapper()`, it is not the same as default `JacksonJsonProvider` instance. Atleast not for `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the order of providers, but it would actually be best to use one provider in this situation:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper defaultMapper;
    private final ObjectMapper specializedMapper;

    public JacksonMapperProvider() {
        defaultMapper = createDefaultMapper();
        specializedMapper = createSpecializedMapper();
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createSpecializedMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
            .registerModule(new SpecializedModule1())
            .registerModule(new SpecializedModule2());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        if (SomeType.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return specializedMapper;
        }
        else {
            return defaultMapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I did initially to get it working, however, I was hoping to keep things separate and agnostic of different modules/areas of the application and to avoid a potential "mega provider" that could result from different mappers being needed.  Can you elaborate on why _"it would be best to use one provider in this situation"_?

Comment: I had a similar problem made worse because we wanted to use MixIns for the Jackson annotations rather that put them on the actual classes. We solved our problem by creating our own `@JsonMixin` annotation and then scanning for all the annotated objects at run time. You could do something similar to configure your `ObjectMapper` dynamically and maintain only one.

Answer (score 0):

The newest way is

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

to get ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES in recent versions of jackson.