# Is there a Scala ES SDK that will let me run the ES Client on my own maintained instances and connect to AWS ES as well?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, sbt, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a Scala Client/SDK that will help me access ES endpoints/libraries both when maintaining my own instances and when maintained by AWS. I found a bunch of them online but they all conflict with the current sbt versions that I use for my project.

Some of the SDKs that I already tried are:

1. https://elastic4s.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/main/tut/docs/
   Issue: Elastic4s needed a higher version of Jackson whereas my application needs a lower version of Jackson to access Finatra.
2. https://github.com/SumoLogic/elasticsearch-client
   Issue: Works with Scala 2.11 and my application runs on Scala 2.12
3. https://index.scala-lang.org/bizreach/elastic-scala-httpclient/elastic-scala-httpclient/
   Issue: The version of ES used here is pretty outdated. It uses ES 5.2.x. I'm looking at a more recent version of ES, something like ES 6.3 because AWS ES supports upto ES 6.3 for now.
4. https://github.com/seratch/AWScala
   Issue: This library is a Scala Client SDK for AWS ES but not for a self-maintained instance of ES.

The versions that I use are:
Scala - 2.12
Finatra - 18.6.0
Jackson - 2.8.4 because Finatra requires this instead of 2.9.4

Comment: I'd go with option #1:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077481/how-to-use-two-versions-of-jackson-1-x-and-2-x-in-the-same-jersey-jax-rs-appli

Comment: I actually found that most effective as well! Thanks!